# Automatically generate a metadata from the given title and author. Is this possible?

Tags: hyperref, metadata

It won't work when I tried my tags below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{%
pdfauthor={\@author},
pdftitle={\@title},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\title{This is my Sample}
\date{}
\maketitle
\author{John J. Tan}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some thing like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% put these before \hypersetup
\title{This is my Sample}
\author{John J. Tan}
\date{}

\makeatletter
 \let\mytitle\@title
 \let\myauthor\@author
\makeatother
\hypersetup{%
pdfauthor={\myauthor},
pdftitle={\mytitle},
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Or even simply

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% put these before \hypersetup
\title{This is my Sample}
\author{John J. Tan}
\date{}

\makeatletter
 \hypersetup{%
   pdfauthor={\@author},
   pdftitle={\@title},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]